# highly similar code apks are released in different countries release google play

Tags: android

Apps with the same function and highly similar code are released in different countries release google play?

for example:
Because the policies of the two countries are different, I need to adapt APKs with different policies for the two countries, but the overall functions of the APK are the same. So can I modify different package names and APP names, and publish two different apps with highly similar codes for two countries? Does this violate google play’s Repetitive Content policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can create 2 or multiple apps from same code.

You can look into [build flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants) to do so, it will allow you to create to create different versions of your app from a single project.

> Does this violate google play’s Repetitive Content policy?

No it won't violate any policy as both app will be owned by you

Refer to this link on how to create flavors of app - [android-product-flavors-build-variants](https://medium.com/simform-engineering/basic-use-of-android-product-flavors-build-variants-315a4e11e435)